# My Bose QuietComfort 35 II headphones are connected to Windows 7 and an iPad: how can I prevent Windows 7 from muting the audio coming from the iPad?

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth, headphones, ipad

My Bose QuietComfort 35 II headphones are connected to Windows 7 and some iPad ([iPad Pro MM172LL/A](https://smile.amazon.com/MM172LL-9-7-inch-Wi-Fi-Model-Refurbished/dp/B07D4PFJ7X?sa-no-redirect=1)): how can I prevent Windows 7 from muting the audio coming from the iPad? Even when no audio is played on Windows 7, I have to disconnect the Bose QuietComfort 35 II headphones from Windows 7 to be able to hear the iPad.

[image: d]

Comment: Are you using the BOSE CONNECT APP?  I am reading your manual now, just trying to see if I can help. I don't know if you have it... https://assets.bose.com/content/dam/Bose_DAM/Web/consumer_electronics/global/products/headphones/qc35_ii/PDF/OG_QuietComfort_35_II_ENGvo.pdf

Comment: @vssher Thanks, I have the Bose Connect application on Android but it is currently turned off. I could turned it on if this allows to fix the issue.

Comment: Using the Conect App: Page 28: Switch between two connected mobile devices 
__1.__ Pause audio on your first mobile device. __2.__ Play audio on your second mobile device.  __Note:__ Your headphones receive phone calls from both devices, despite which device is playing audio. I think this means you can just Pause the audio instead of disconnecting the device.  Hope I helped.

Comment: You need to read pp. 28 and 29.  Good Luck.

Comment: @vssher Thanks, pausing the audio works on all devices (iPad and phones) but not on my computer running Windows: when I pause the audio on Microsoft Windows I still can't hear the iPad :-/

Comment: If you don't use "Handsfree Telephony" or the like, have you tried turning that off? Or is this the real reason you connect to Windows with the headset? I'm just guessing here, but I saw a post at answers.microsoft and this was a helpful answer. Sorry that other hadn't helped, I do not own a BOSE anything here in the U.S.A., though I did have speakers in my car way back in the 80's which were BOSE. Good luck.

Comment: Have you seen this page? https://plugable.com/2017/02/07/bluetooth-audio-problems-cant-get-your-bose-quietcomfort-35-connected-check-here-first/ __Newer Bluetooth audio devices are being designed with a mobile-first mentality....__